# Dynkin diagrams in Yang-Mills theory

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, mp.mathematical-physics

I was searching for applications of Dynkin diagrams in physics and came across this site: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/McKay+correspondence but I can't quite understand how useful Dynkin diagrams are in the Yang-Mills theory.

Can someone help me out?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Forget the fancy stuff for a second; do you know what the ordinary McKay correspondence is? At the most basic level it just says that the finite subgroups of $SU(2)$ are indexed by ADE (i.e., simply laced) Dynkin diagrams.

Comment: Yeah, I do know that but I can't connect what I know with what is written in that link. Thank you very much for answering!